# Flutter geolocator package is giving negative latitude on IOS app and correct coordinates on Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gps

```
double lat;
double lon;

var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

lat = position.longitude;
lon = position.latitude;
```

Im trying to get the device location and i have the same project building the IOS and Android App but for IOS im getting the GPS location as 37.785834,-122.406417 and android 35.6496833,139.7517317 which is the correct.

if i change the `lat = -(position.longitude);` then it makes the android app gives the negative latitude. any way to avoid this without having separate projects for each apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using real device on the iOS part.

The Geolocation shown on Simulator is a preset value which can be modified via the iOS Simulator menu, go to **Debug** -> **Location** -> **Custom Location**. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ios simulator
Features -> Location -> Custom Location. T
[image]

location > in Features

[image]

and can change longitude